# Why does an exponential distribution have the property of memorylessness?

Tags: random-variables, exponential-distribution

Ok so let's consider an example, suppose our random variable X=number of minutes in which the bus arrives and the mean is 20 min. 
And suppose I have already waited for 23 mins and was wondering whether the bus will arrive within the next minute, so according to me, to calculate that probability I have to look at the area under the curve from 0 to 24 minutes, but that isn't the case. I looked at many videos online but they all had a more mathematical proof rather than a logical one.
So what I'm looking for here is a more logical proof rather than a mathematical one.
Could someone please help me figure it out?

PS:Please try to use layman terms as far as possible.

Comment: The title of your question seems very different from the question body.  Also, what are the hypotheses in the problem you are trying to solve?  Is the waiting time for the bus supposed to be exponentially distributed?

Comment: Yes its supposed to be exponential distributed

Comment: So the way I see it, I have been told that we do not have to calculate the area under the curve from 0 to 24 because exponential distribution has the property of memorylessness, so I phrased the title in that way, that why does it have the property of memorylessness because of which I'm getting the wrong answer

Comment: As for the hypothesis, that word seems very distant to me as I haven't gotten there in my studies

Comment: If you are told that it is exponentially distributed, that's the hypothesis.  The fact that it's memoryless, means that it doesn't matter how long you have been waiting;  the expected waiting time is the same no matter how long you have been waiting.

Comment: Yeah so @saulspatz why the heck is it so is my question

Comment: It's a property of the distribution; the proof should be in your textbook, or your lecture notes.  If not, you can easily find it online.

Comment: I'm looking for more of a logical proof than a mathematical one actually

Comment: This is a mathematical statement.  Only a mathematical proof makes sense.

Comment: The probability of independent events is multiplied. An exponential is the continuous version of repeated multiplication